# How to import Suprema java classes?

Tags: java, netbeans, import

Can any body help? I bought a Suprema sdk, so I want to use it in my web application through an applet. So I am using netbeans 8.0, when I run the java examples, I get errors that the packages do not exist. Thank in advance.

Comment: Nearly impossible to answer this without more explanation, description.

Comment: Simply put, I need steps to run Suprema Finger print java example given in the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I create [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxMy-goCVTU5ME03VEhIOTBFdGs/view?usp=sharing) jar file with classes, only import in your project

Comment: thanks, i was able to create java classes that map the scanner dll and the matcher dll